# Pick from a list and save it to database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am creating a website with Codeigniter 3 HMVC style for a client and he wants have a function on this page where the logged user has the choice of picking their own news. For example if a user chooses Juventus then he will recieve all the news added where Juventus is named. Basically like a add to basket or cart thing and I have never done something like this so here is what I have created:

Controller

```
    class Usernews extends MY_Controller{

    function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('model_usernews');
    $this->load->module('template');

}

function search(){
      $data['pageTitle'] = "User news";
    $search_name = $this->input->post('band');
    $data['bands'] = $this->model_usernews->get_clubs($search_name);
     $data['module'] = "usernews";
    $data['view_file'] = "usernews";
    $this->template->user_news($data);
}
```

}

Model

```
   class Model_usernews extends CI_Model {

    function get_table(){
    $table = "bands";
    return $table;
    }

    function get_clubs($keyword) {
    $table = $this->get_table();
    $this->db->like('band_name', $keyword, 'both');
    $this->db->order_by('band_name');
    $query=$this->db->get($table);
    return $query;
    }
```

and part of the View

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 ">
        <!-- USER BAND LIST -->
        <!-- LIST OF ARTICLES -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
     <div class="row">
     <?php $attributes = array('id' => 'list_of_bands');
          echo form_open('usernews/search',$attributes); ?>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="band"
       placeholder="Search">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" >OK</button>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
       <?php  $num_rows = $listing->num_rows();
        if($num_rows > 0){ ?>
        <ul id="the_bands" class="list-unstyled">
        <li> <?php foreach ($listing->result() as $row){?>
            <li><?php echo $row->band_name; ?>" ><button id="add_band"  
            class="btn btn-default btn-sm" >Add to list</button></li>
          <?php } 
           } else{
            echo "<p>No bands with that name</p>"; 
             } ?>
            </div> 
            </div>
```

I can search for the bands in the database but now I am clueless.

Answer (score 0):

In your view use `$bands` instead of `$listing`.